# How do I use multiple document classes in Actionscript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

OK, I am completely new to Actionscirpt 3. I am now trying to make a breakout game. I would like to use four document classes, background.as for drawing the background, player.as for creating the paddle, blocks.as for creating the bricks, and ball.as for the ball. But it seems to me that you can only set one .as file to your .fla file. So how can I get access to four document classes?

I defined a new class called BreakoutGame.as, and tried to somehow 'link' the other four classes to it, like:

```
package  {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import background;
import player;
public class BreakoutGame extends MovieClip {

    public function BreakoutGame()
    {
        // constructor code
    }
}

}
```

Well, nothing happened. I am wondering how I can get the other classes together. Anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: You can only have one document class in Flash. This might help: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/quickstart/external_files_as3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Lee Burrows mentioned use can use only one document class, but you can use as many custom display classes as you want, so create MovieClip in the library for background (and associate your background.as class file with if) and put it to the scene manually. Do the same for every custom class you need.

You can also give the instance name to these movie clips and create correspond protected fields in your  document class, so you will be able to manage these clips in your document class code (for example change visibility)

Comment: I am trying that, but why does it keep telling me 'call to a possibly undefined method Background' and 'Access of undefined property background'?

Comment: OK. I finally resolved it, after several hours' tedious searching and asking. Thank you fsbmain and Lee. What do you think about adobe flash? I guess it's pretty bad, not easy to use at all.

Comment: Try something like FlashDevelop if you want to make everything in code, or even mix it with the Flash IDE. It's a free IDE (Visual Studio like) for Flex SDK. I use it for my AS2 and 3 and had forgot about Flash at all.

Comment: @rcdmk Thanks for your advice, I will try FlashDevelop.

Comment: i dont think flash is that difficult - ActionScript is a pretty standard language - but it does have a steep learning curve early on. Stick with it if you can.

Comment: @phil AS3 is really easy to use if you have any kind of background on OOP (Object Oriented Programming). I'd suggest first taking a look at basic principles of OOP, Flash `DisplayList` and Event handling.